# Omitting “to” due to implicit elements

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

I don’t know if there’s a general rule for when to omit "to" before a verb that normally requires it. In my native language, the verbs in bold in the example below would all be in infinitive (to + root form of the verb, e.g. "to wash") so it often confuses me, but if this logic of mine is correct, it'll help a lot.

I think that in the following case "to" can be omitted, because there are implicit elements (between brackets) to consider:

*If I could, I would do all that is still undone: [I would] **wash** the floor, [I would] **do** the laundry, [I would] **clean** the windows, and finally [I would] **prepare** the dish.*

Is this logic correct? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The analysis is misleading, because you could also say this: *There are so many things **to** do: **wash** the floor, **do** the laundry, **clean** the windows, and **prepare** the dish.*  But there is nothing being omitted (or implied) that would warrant the lack of *to* in a fashion similar to what you propose in your sentence. (For instance, **to wash** would make no sense in this context.) The reason you can omit it is different than you think.

Comment: If English is not one of your native languages, then you're doing awfully well, far better than I have in any of my language pursuits. Excellent delivery/diction. On this matter though - "...I would do all that is missing to be done..." - this really doesn't work. Many other forms might work, but not that. For example: "...I would do all that is still undone..." or "...I would do all that needs doing..." or remain "...I would do all remains..."

Comment: Thank you, @Yishmeray ! I accepted one of your suggestions and edited the text.

Comment: None of those verbs require to. To is not about requiring a verb....To goes to purpose or to link two parts of a sentence.In fact, your samples show that....

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're dealing with **bare infinitives**. They are called "bare" because they don't have the word *to* in front of them, as you are used to (but they are still infinitives!).

This is where your "implicit elements" come into play: the verb *would* is an example of a **modal verb**, and these verbs (generally) take a bare infinitive. The word "*to*" couldn't be placed into the sentence as written, so it isn't "omitted." Instead, it's missing because of the concept of *bare infinitives*.

One more thing: as has been mentioned in the comments, the construction "*all that **is missing to be done***" needs to be tweaked a little bit. You can tweak this in several ways, including:

> I would do all that is **yet** to be done...
>
> I would do all that is **not done**/**undone**...
>
> I would do all that **has** not **been done**...

Also, make sure that you change *prepared* to ***prepare***, which is the bare infinitive.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to answer my own question, there is nothing implicit and “to” is not used in the example simply because the base/bare form of the infinitive is demanded, (as pointed out by @Kman3). This form would be used even without the “I would” in the first clause: “There are so many things to do: wash the floor, do the laundry, clean the windows, and prepare the dish”, quoting @Jason Bassford ‘s comment.

You must use the bare form of infinitive in the example (both “If I could, I would do all that is still undone: wash…” and “There are so many things to do: wash…”), simply because the verbs which come after the colon are connected to the verb “to do” (already in infinitive) in the first clause and “to” is dropped in such cases.